# Do I understand correctly how a split system should work in AB tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test, random-allocation

I have a question about how a split system should work.
I have a product. Which looks like eBay.
We conducted an experiment that should increase the number of users who choose one of the categories.
What's the point, I have a Default option that looks like the photo (Group A), B group (Icons made large), C group (Same thing only slightly different).
There was also a large number of users who did not participate in the experiment but saw the default design.
The experiment was conducted for 2 weeks.
Each of the groups had more than 100K users and 300K users were without groups.

I decided to conduct an AA test, taking a group of 300K who did not participate in the experiment, but saw the same design as group A.
And I got the % of unique users who click on the category that is first in the list for one group 50% and for the second (larger) group 55%.

Logically, given the size of the samples and the fact that randomization should have worked correctly. We should always get approximately the same numbers. Right?

[image]

Comment: (+1) "*Right*" but 1. We don't know how variable is that metric. 2. how successful that randomisation was. 3. if there were seasonality, outliers, or telemetry/infrastructure issues. For all intended purposes, what you see is unlikely but not impossible. Also kudos for running the A/A test.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks for the answer.
Well, seasonality shouldn't have an impact, because we take groups in the same period.
And what about variability? Are you saying that it's normal for AA tests to have 5% differences in some metrics? (I just didn't have the experience and imagined that in AA tests we should get very similar results with such large samples)

Comment: You can try and resample the "untreated" group and see what is the expected variability there. I don't think it is "normal" but there might be multiple reasons for that. For example, maybe latency in the arm-assignment mechanism affected the click-through-rate.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks, I'll try it. This is my first case. I'm June. And I always think that everything should be working fine by now:)

Comment: "*everything should be working fine*" I love the smell of optimism in the morning. (+1). Good luck! :)